# Best way to cast Collection<dynamic> into Collection<double>?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have collection of type `dynamic`, which I feed with `int`, `float` and `double`. Now I need to cast this Collection into Collection.

```
Collection<dynamic> values = new Collection<dynamic>();
values.Add((double)1);
values.Add((double)1.654654);
values.Add((double)10000.654654);

// How?
Collection<double> doubleValues = (Collection<double>)values;
```

I would love to avoid iterate through whole collection, because its count can be greater than 5000000. Any help?

Comment: You will need to iterate and cast.

Comment: May I ask you why are you using dynamic in the first place?

Comment: @ken2k The data I'm reading can be in two shapes, Collection<double> or Collection<double[]>. So, I am using dynamic to accomodate both.

Comment: why not object instead of dynamic? also, how are you planning to flatten the double[] types?

Comment: and then first you say *which I feed with int, float and double* but the example says `values.Add((double)1)`... one or the other :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you'll have to iterate and cast...

```
double[] values2 = new double[values.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
{
    values2[i] = values[i];
}
```

Or better try to cast before adding to the `Collection<>`

Note that a `Collection<dynamic>` is very like a `Collection<object>` (if you do `typeof(Collection<dynamic>) == typeof(Collection<object>)` you get `true`). `dynamic` is a trick of the compiler. This means that your numbers have been "boxed" inside `object`s. So for this reason it is clear why you can't do what you want :-)

Now... if you need to use every element only once, this wouldn't slow down anything and it wouldn't eat any memory:

```
public class MyDoubleList : IList<double>
{
    public readonly Collection<dynamic> Base;

    public MyDoubleList(Collection<dynamic> @base)
    {
        Base = @base;
    }

    // Now reimplement all the IList<double> methods by using the 
    // Base collection, like:


    public int IndexOf(double item)
    {
        return Base.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public double this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return Base[index];
        }
        set
        {
            Base[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public void Add(double item)
    {
        Base.Add(item);
    }

    // And so on
}
```

It is an adaptor (as in the pattern name) between `Collection<dynamic>` and `IList<double>` that casts "on demand". Note the problems:

```
// the same conversion has been done twice, slow :-)
double v1 = adaptor[0];
double v2 = adaptor[0];
```

and then

```
// 1 is added as a double, and then boxed in the Collection<dynamic>
// slow :-)
adaptor.Add(1);
```

Comment: I am already casting before adding data into dynamic collection

Comment: Read my comment in question. Replied to ken2k

Answer (score 1):

Since you're casting all the values to type `double` then you can just do this to get the values:

```
var myDoubles = collection.OfType<double>();
```

Or even better, if you know that you're going to be adding doubles to the collection, just make the original collection type `double` rather than `dynamic`.